# How do I use Kibana for multiuser

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have Kibana up and running and it is beautifully showing the data based on my params.

How can I use Kibana in protected environment? To explain my intent:
How can I share Kibana with users, but not exposing the ElasticSearch instance.
The only way it (If I am not mistaken) is to give a user link with my dashboard, but as I mentioned that is path to ElasticSearch instance itself.

Comment: It looks like Search Guard has support for this: https://github.com/floragunncom/search-guard-docs/blob/master/multitenancy.md

Answer (score 1):

With kibana3, most people solve this with nginx proxy rules.  Also check out the Elasticsearch "[shield](http://www.elasticsearch.org/overview/shield/)" product.